# Adding CSS to an element created after document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently asked a question about how to make an h1 with javascript and determine what the innerHTML will be. I tried every answer and none of them worked so I'm posting my entire code in case I have something in there that requires a different solution.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/time.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div id="time">
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="pull-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">

        <div class="container">
          <h1>Forum Signatures</h1>
          <p>A hobbyist art style wherein the artist uses various methods to create appealing effects around a render cut from a previously existing image.</p>
          <!--- <a href="#">Learn More</a> --->
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="neighborhood-guides">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Favorite Pieces</h2>
          <!---<p>Not sure where to stay? We've created neighborhood guides for cities all around the world.</p>--->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/The-Colors-438254150">
                  <img class="colors" src="images/colors.png"></a>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Schitz-443257857">
                  <img class="schitz" src="images/schitz.png"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Arcade-Sona-443074789">
                  <img class="sona" src="images/sona.png"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Mass-Effect-Signature-443034977">
                  <img class="mass" src="images/mass_effect.png"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Test-your-Luck-449429967">
                  <img class="tf" src="images/tf.png"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Super-Serial-442310653">
                  <img class="serial" src="images/serial.png"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Teemo-438254430">
                  <img class="teemo" src="images/teemo.png"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Death-From-Above-448908808">
                  <img class="assassin" src="images/assassin.png"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://krucifiks.deviantart.com/art/Abstract-Tag-345903925">
                  <img class="abstract" src="images/abstract.png"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <a class="images" href="http://shniper1337.deviantart.com/art/Normal-is-just-too-boring-452311932">
                  <img class="normal" src="images/normal.png"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="learn-more">
        <h2>Other Work</h2>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <a href="#"><h3>Web Design</h3></a>
              <p>Extensive experience with HTML5 and CSS3. Multiple websites created, unique perspective of a designer and IT major combined.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <a href="#"><h3>Graphic Design</h3></a>
              <p>Strong background in Photoshop as well as professional experience in Illustrator and InDesign.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <a href="#"><h3>Software Engineering</h3></a>
              <p>Information Technology student with a passion for logic and programming. Experience with Javascript, some JQuery and some Python.</p>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(function() {

        $('#time').animate({
          right: '0%'
        }, 2000).delay(1500).animate({
          right: '100%'
        }, 2000);
      });

    </script>
    <noscript><link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"></noscript>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #495987;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#time {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  right: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;

}

#time h1: {
  color: #FFAB23;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 0px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #111;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #495987;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
  color: #E16024;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFAB23;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('images/design.png');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #cac9b9;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #222222;
  max-width: 430px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.learn-more {
  background-color: #495987;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #E16024;
  text-align: center;
}

.learn-more h2 {
  font-family: 'Arimo 700', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F3B600;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #111;
}

.learn-more h3:hover {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #FFAB23;
}

.learn-more p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #BFD3EE;
}

.learn-more a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.neighborhood-guides {
  background-color: #495987;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
  color: #F3B600;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #111;
}

.neighborhood-guides p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.normal {
  width: 150px;
}

.colors {
  width: 130px;
}

.thumbnail {
  transition: .4s linear;
  transition: opacity .3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #111;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  transform: scale(2.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.2);
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #111;;

}

.container:hover .thumbnail img:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

JS

```
function getStylesheet() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
      if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
       var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
       h1.innerHTML = "Good Morning!";

       document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
      }
      if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 12) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='morning.css' type='text/css'>");
       var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
       h1.innerHTML = "Good Morning!";

       document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
      }
      if (12 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='day.css' type='text/css'>");
       var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        h1.id= "timeh1";
        document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
        document.getElementById("timeh1").innerHTML = "Good Afternoon!";

       document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
      }
      if (17 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='evening.css' type='text/css'>");
       var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
       h1.innerHTML = "Good Evening!";

       document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
      }
      if (22 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
       var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
       h1.innerHTML = "Good Evening!";

       document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
      }
}

getStylesheet();
```

So I'm trying to create an h1 in the #time id which starts off of the screen and animates to the middle and then goes back off using JQuery. Even when I comment out all css and the JQuery the h1 does not appear on the screen.

Please Help.

Comment: in the line #time h1: { - in your CSS remove the ':'

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: no, there are further problems, but removing the ':' will help to apply the styles. Look here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxPypQ

Comment: `document.write` doesn't work after a page has loaded (in general not a good technique to depend on). Instead append those `<link>` tags to the DOM as you're doing with your H1.

Answer (score 0):

For one, looks like when you create the h1 it should be like:

```
document.createElement("H1");
```

note the capital H. Refer here: [createElement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp)

Comment: if (12 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17) {
      
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='day.css' type='text/css'>");
        var h1 = document.createElement("H1");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Good Afternoon!");
        document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
        h.appendChild(t);
        
      } Also does not work

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please set up an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so it would be easier for others to tinker with your code example. It also helps us help you if the title depicts the actual problem you're describing.

Solving the issue mentioned in your title: dynamically created elements automatically get existing styles applied to them. See this simple [example](https://jsfiddle.net/x257hpw3/1/).

Now looking at your JavaScript, I'd say the issue (besides some errors like multiple declarations of h1 variable) is those dynamic CSS files you're trying to append to the DOM. I suggest you have your CSS files included from the start (or have the styles in one CSS file to reduce the number of requests). Also, there is a lot of repetitive code you're writing in each if statement. Here's the same thing optimized (imagine the time related styles included in your CSS already).

```
function assignTimeStyle() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getHours(),
      h1 = document.createElement("h1"),
      text,
      style;

  if (0 <= currentTime && currentTime < 5) {
   text = "Good Morning!";
   style = "night";
  }
  if (5 <= currentTime && currentTime < 12) {
    text = "Good Morning!";
    style = "morning";
  }
  if (12 <= currentTime && currentTime < 17) {
    text = "Good Afternoon!";
    style = "day";
  }
  if (17 <= currentTime && currentTime < 22) {
   text = "Good Evening!";
   style = "evening";
  }
  if (22 <= currentTime && currentTime <= 24) {
   text = "Good Evening!";
   style = "night";
  }

  h1.innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("time").appendChild(h1);
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add(style);
}
```

As you see, we're adding a certain style class to the body element based on the time of day. That way you can style your elements through the body element in this example. A good practise though is to narrow down the parent element as much as possible.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure what my problem was. I put the link to time.js in the #time div and that fixed it. Your fix didn't fix it unless it was in the #time div as well. But there should be a way to do this without needing to put it there right?

Comment: That seems to imply you had an issue with your `<script>` tag order - does time.js depend on jQuery? Because atm you're including it before the jQuery script tag. All in all, your comment was a bit confusing. Can you elaborate what you mean by "put the link to time.js in the #time div"? Did you place a `<script>` tag inside a div element?

Comment: yes i put the <script src="time.js> inside of the div #time. My time.js does affect the jquery at the bottom because the time.js makes an h1 that animates using jquery.